# Rails -Couldn't find User with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been developing a site based on the Hartl's guide. I want to move the password reset functionality to it own partial.

I created a partial, _passreset.html.erb. Essentially a copy of the _form that only shows your username and displays the password/password_confirm fields.

But I'm not even getting there. On the show.html.erb page (the profile page), I have links to Edit and Password Reset. Here is the code:

```
   <% if current_user.admin? || current_user == @user %>
   <%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_path(@user) %> | 
   <%= link_to "Password Reset", user_passreset_path(@user)%>
   <% end %>
```

When I click on the "Password Reset" link, I get the follow error: 
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show
Couldn't find User with 'id'=passreset

The source is my users controller set_user function:

```
def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

The route for the new function looks like this:

```
resources :users do
resources :articles
get 'passreset'
end
```

rake routes shows this line:

```
 user_passreset GET    /users/:user_id/passreset(.:format)                 users#passreset
```

I've also explicitly declared the route (get 'users/passreset'), it doesn't make a difference.

Why is it looking for an id of 'passreset'? I don't get it.

I don't think it matters, but this is the passrest function from my users controller:

```
 def passreset
 respond_to do |format|
  if @user.update(user_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Password was      successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status:  :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you look at your route output , it is looking for a `user_id` as part of the nested route

```
user_passreset GET    /users/:user_id/passreset(.:format)
```

if you make the route on the member, it should  match based on `:id`  again.

```
resources :users do
  resources :articles
  member do 
    get 'passreset'
  end
end
```

Comment: This got me past the error. I had to change the link to read passreset_user_path. And now....I'm getting different error:( param is missing or the value is empty: user. Its pointing to my strong params statement. *Sigh*

Comment: well open a new question, showing your form and the strong params  code.  but my guess is that your form is just a form_tag, not a form_for @user, so you params has doesn't contain the :user key that everything is under?

Comment: I'm going to take a crack at it in the morning, and open a new question if I can't sort it out. Thank you Doon.